# How to investigate front-end

Tags: css

I have a webpage on which I have two radio buttons:

[image: radio buttons without mouse over]

It's not implemented by me, I'm wondering what is causing, that when mouse is over it, there is one additional (ugly in my opinion) line:

[image: radio buttons with mouse over and line]

There are 5 levels of DIVs (it's not really a button), following code is from FF (just for your imagination, I cannot change it):

```
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft BPMHorizontalRadio dojoxCheckedMultiSelect" id="widget_dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0" widgetid="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="comboButtonNode"/>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="selectNode" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper" data-dojo-attach-event="onmousedown:_onMouseDown,onclick:focus">
        <select class="dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelect dojoxCheckedMultiSelectHidden" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" id="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
            <option value="0" label="0" selected="selected"/>
        </select>
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="wrapperDiv">
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelectedOption" id="dijit__Widget_60" widgetid="dijit__Widget_60" aria-selected="true">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_60">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label">Admin System ID</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem" id="dijit__Widget_61" widgetid="dijit__Widget_61" aria-selected="false">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_61">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="false" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label">Party ID</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I noticed is, that div with ID dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0 have additional CSS classes on hover - `dijitHover` and `dojoxCheckedMultiSelectHover`.

I do not know how to check those in "Rules", because when I moved my mouse it's gone (of course).

I tried also to ":hover" options in FF/Chrome, but that line is not shown...

[image: Tried Chrome's ":hover"]

**edit 1:**

I tried what I understood from `outline: none`:

[image: outline none on top div]

I set that to top div, but no chnge in behavior...

**edit 2:**

As I wrote in a comment, I do not reallyknow which DIV is causing a problem, I tried suggested `div:hover`, but it is still the same...

[image]

**edit 3:**

I tried also `div { outline: none !important }` and `div { border: none !important }`, still the same.

Now I see, that in Chrome, there is "Event Listener" on first div, but JS is minimized, what can I do with that?

[image]

**edit 4:**

I found pretty print, but that JS doesn't seems to be the right thing to check (seems to me like event handling)

```
            function _a83(type, _a84) {
                var _a85 = function(node, _a86) {
                    return on(node, type, function(evt) {
                        if (_a84) {
                            return _a84(evt, _a86);
                        }
                        if (!dom.isDescendant(evt.relatedTarget, node)) {
                            return _a86.call(this, evt);
                        }
                    });
                };
                _a85.bubble = function(_a87) {
                    return _a83(type, function(evt, _a88) {
                        var _a89 = _a87(evt.target);
                        var _a8a = evt.relatedTarget;
                        if (_a89 && (_a89 != (_a8a && _a8a.nodeType == 1 && _a87(_a8a)))) {
                            return _a88.call(_a89, evt);
                        }
                    });
                }
                ;
                return _a85;
            }
```

Comment: try `outline:none` on focus or onhover

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't ring a bell. Can you add steps for dummies?

Comment: okk wait until I post some code

Comment: @NikhilGhuse check my edit also, maybe you meant that... But that didn't work...

Comment: on that div , on the debugging tab when inspecting element, look for `filter` tab open and click `:hover` should see `css` that does this, must be a border added to :hover state.

Comment: honnestly dont think this has to do with `outline`, its a border, but since we cant see the `css` im taking a guess, try `border: none !important;` on the element or `div`  for `class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem" id="dijit__Widget_61"` with :hover just to see if its maybe a border.. like `.dijitReset.dojoxMultiSelectItem:hover {border: none !important;}` , or the `id`

Comment: on **Edit 3** > open `styles` tab then on the right top conner you wil see `:hov` click it the for each div > force element state `:hover` then you wil see the css added on one of the divs for :hover state.

Comment: Thanks, focus works fine, but hover is not showing the line...

Comment: @Betlista try the hover state on each div one of them should have the css, could be on focus state aswell .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this `div` i think `.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper` , looks like this:

```css
#dijit__Widget_60, #dijit__Widget_61 {
  display: inline-block;

}

.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_61, .dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_60 {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft BPMHorizontalRadio dojoxCheckedMultiSelect" id="widget_dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0" widgetid="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="comboButtonNode"/>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="selectNode" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper" data-dojo-attach-event="onmousedown:_onMouseDown,onclick:focus">
        <select class="dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelect dojoxCheckedMultiSelectHidden" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" id="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
            <option value="0" label="0" selected="selected"/>
        </select>
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="wrapperDiv">
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelectedOption" id="dijit__Widget_60" widgetid="dijit__Widget_60" aria-selected="true">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_60">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label">Admin System ID</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem" id="dijit__Widget_61" widgetid="dijit__Widget_61" aria-selected="false">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_61">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="false" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label">Party ID</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A fix for now just to see if its the case, (on **Edit 3** > open styles tab then on the right top corner you wil see `:hov` click it the for each div > force element state `:hover` then you wil see the **css** added on one of the divs for `:hover` state.)

Then add this to that div especially this one (for :hover state) , `.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper`

**Example:**

```css
#dijit__Widget_60, #dijit__Widget_61 {
  display: inline-block;

}

.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_61, .dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_60 {
  border-top: 1px solid #efefef;
}

.dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_61, .dijit.dijitReset.dijitInline.dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper:hover #dijit__Widget_60 {
  border: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft BPMHorizontalRadio dojoxCheckedMultiSelect" id="widget_dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0" widgetid="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="comboButtonNode"/>
    <div data-dojo-attach-point="selectNode" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxCheckedMultiSelectWrapper" data-dojo-attach-event="onmousedown:_onMouseDown,onclick:focus">
        <select class="dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelect dojoxCheckedMultiSelectHidden" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode,focusNode" style="-moz-user-select: none;" tabindex="0" id="dojox_form_CheckedMultiSelect_0">
            <option value="0" label="0" selected="selected"/>
        </select>
        <div data-dojo-attach-point="wrapperDiv">
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelectedOption" id="dijit__Widget_60" widgetid="dijit__Widget_60" aria-selected="true">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_60">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="true" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_60_radio_label">Admin System ID</div>
            </div>
            <div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem" id="dijit__Widget_61" widgetid="dijit__Widget_61" aria-selected="false">
                <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_61">
                    <input role="radio" aria-checked="false" class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:_onClick" value="on" tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61" style="-moz-user-select: none;" aria-labelledby="div_91_label dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label" name="div_91_radiogroup" type="radio">
                </div>
                <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_61_radio_label">Party ID</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the end if you found it remove from css file, `!important` just for testing purposes.

Comment: I have no idea, how you found that. I didn't realize, that in "Styles" it can be added somewhere in the middle. At the end the problem was with `background-image` :-/ Next time I have to check all divs in hierarchy with filter in Styles... Thanks! It's sad, that "force element state" is not working as expected, that was part of a confusion definitely..

Comment: So you fixed the problem? yess man sometimes it can be such a headache with allot of `divs` using 'force element state', so that was what i was trying to tell you the only way to find it is to check all the `divs` in the hierarchy as you mentioned.